# Is it safe to use DateTime.Now as a default route value in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following in an Area Registration of my ASP.NET MVC 3 project running on .NET Framework v4.0:

```
context.MapRoute(null,
                 "YardJob/{location}/{from}",
                 new { controller = "YardJob", 
                       action = "List", 
                       from = DateTime.Now });
```

My question is:
If the routing engine uses the default route value for 'from', will the List method on the controller always be invoked with the current date and time?

Is there any caching in the routing engine that may cause the default route value to be reused among requests?

Thanks,

Comment: If you are always intending to use DateTime.Now, why pass it in the route?

Comment: With that route, the from always take the DateTime of the moment when route register in the route map, this happens when the application starts.

Comment: Sometimes an alternate value is supplied.

Comment: @Zachdev so, this may sound silly, but how often does the application start? With each request?

Comment: with each request? no my friend, the aplication start when the aplication pool start up the aplication, for example, in development when you compile and run your aplication or in production when publish the app and the app pool recicle.

Comment: @Zachdev if you want to answer the question, I will mark it as the answer. I was under the impression that the default value would always be the current date, but it will be the date the when the application last started. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the process of register the routes is executed when the application starts, so if you put DateTime.Now the default parameter for from field would be the time when the application starts, change only when the AppPool recycles

when application starts?
when the first resource (such as a page) in an ASP.NET application is requested. The Application_Start method in Global.asax is called only one time during the life cycle of an application. You can use this method to perform startup tasks such as loading data into the cache and initializing static values.

check out the [life cicle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot, saved me a big headache.

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer explains, this isn't possible. However, for the sake of completeness, here is how you would work around this:

**Route:**

```
context.MapRoute(null,
    "YardJob/{location}/{from}",
     new { controller = "YardJob", 
     action = "List", 
     from = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

**Controller action:**

```
public ActionResult List (string location, DateTime from)
{
    if (from == null)
        from = DateTime.Now;
}
```